# `std::unique_ptr` makes compiling error `candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable`

Tags: c++, constructor, static-methods, unique-ptr

`std::unique_ptr` makes compiling error `candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable`

Let me declare it by these code below.

Code that makes compiling error is:

Code0: **error**

```
#include <iostream>
class A {
public:
    static A str(){ return A();}
    std::unique_ptr<int> pi;
    A(): pi(new int(0)){}
};
```

Error is:

```
test.cpp:4:26: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'A'
            static A str(){ return A();}
                                   ^~~
test.cpp:2:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: expects an l-value for 1st argument
class A {
  ^
test.cpp:7:3: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 1 was provided
            A(){
            ^
1 error generated.
```

But all these examples below are **ok**

Code1: **ok**

```
#include <iostream>
class A {
public:
    //static A str(){ return A();}
    std::unique_ptr<int> pi;
    A(): pi(new int(0)){}
};
```

Code2: **ok**

```
#include <iostream>
class A {
public:
    static A str(){ return A();}
    //std::unique_ptr<int> pi;
    A()/*: pi(new int(0))*/{}
};
```

Code3: **ok**

```
#include <iostream>
class A {
public:
    static A str(){ return A();}
    std::shared_ptr<int> pi;
    A(): pi(new int(0)){}
};
```

Im using `g++`, version info

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 (clang-700.1.76)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0
Thread model: posix
```

Could anyone explain it?

Comment: Compiles fine here, are you using `-std=c++11`? And are you including `<memory>`?

Comment: @orlp with `-std=c++11`, it is **ok** even if `<memory>` is not included

Comment: The code is correct in C++11, and incorrect in C++03 (because `std::unique_ptr` didn't exist in C++03, among other things)

Comment: @M.M: [shared_ptr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/) is also from `C++11`. What is the difference from [unique_ptr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/unique_ptr/)?

Comment: @user3909241 `unique_ptr` is not copyable. It is only movable.  In C++11 `return A();` is a move operation, but in C++03 it is a copy operation because C++03 did not have moves.

Comment: @M.M I got it. Thanks captain!